# How to Install GDAL to use rgdal in R?

Tags: r, gdal

I downloaded GDAL from GISInternals with python bindings, I already have python installed on my computer. But when I use R, it doesn't detect gdal installation instead gives error when use command `gdal_setinstallation()`.
How to remove this error so that R can find GDAL installed.

Comment: Is it on your system Path? What OS are you using. What is the error you get?

Comment: You might need to install [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) package through command `install.packages("rgdal", dependencies = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes, It is in my system path. My OS is windows 10 64 bit. Initially, I did the same procedure on my other PC with windows 7, where I got an error that gdal installation is broken. In this windows 10 pc, when I run command of set installation, it gives information of gdal installed and version info etc. But batch_transalation gives no results in desired folder. and list.files commands gives "NULL". The translation tool isn't working I guess. But don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I have installed rgdal package as well.

Answer (score 2):

If like me you are using using Linux run the following in case you are missing system dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin proj-bin libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

Then (as per @MYaseen208 comment) from within R use:

```
install.packages("rgdal", dependencies = TRUE)
```